# JPAContainer add component in table?

Tags: java, vaadin7

I'm looking for a how to add a component in my table. My table is using a JPAContainer as datasource. I'm trying using addContainerProperty but doesn't work and returns an exception.

I'm trying this

```
private final CustomJPAContainer<Curriculum> datasource = new CustomJPAContainer<Curriculum>(Curriculum.class);

Button btnView = new Button();
Table tabela = new Table("",datasource);
tabela.addContainerProperty("View", Button.class, null);


//exception 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.JPAContainer.addContainerProperty(JPAContainer.java:666)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractSelect.addContainerProperty(AbstractSelect.java:806)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.addContainerProperty(Table.java:4260)
    at br.ind.ibg.views.VisualizarCurriculum.buildLayout(VisualizarCurriculum.java:58)
    at br.ind.ibg.views.VisualizarCurriculum.<init>(VisualizarCurriculum.java:36)
    at br.ind.ibg.utils.MenuSistema$1.menuSelected(MenuSistema.java:60)
    at com.vaadin.ui.MenuBar.changeVariables(MenuBar.java:186)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.changeVariables(ServerRpcHandler.java:396)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleBurst(ServerRpcHandler.java:221)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:111)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:91)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:37)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1382)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Any idea ?

/** edited */
I solved the problem using setGeneratedColumn()

Here how I did.

```
public class ButtonColumnGenerator implements Table.ColumnGenerator{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Object generateCell(Table source, Object itemId, Object columnId) {
        Property prop = source.getItem(itemId).getItemProperty(columnId);
        Button btnView = new Button();
        btnView.setData(itemId);
        btnView.setDescription("Curriculum: " + itemId);
        btnView.setIcon(new ThemeResource("../icons/eye.png"));             
        btnView.setWidth("20px");
        btnView.setHeight("20px");
        btnView.setStyleName(Reindeer.BUTTON_LINK);     

        return btnView;
    }
}


/*** my app */
Button btnView = new Button();
Table tabela = new Table("",datasource);
tabela.setVisibleColumns(new Object[]{"idCurriculum", "nome", "cpf"});      
tabela.setColumnHeaders(new String[] {"#", "Nome", "Cpf"});
tabela.addGeneratedColumn("", new ButtonColumnGenerator());
```

now works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding UI components to the data source of a select component (Table, Tree, TreeTable, ComboBox, ...) is the wrong approach for your problem. The container data source of a Table component only contains the data model of the table and not the components that will display this data.

So, instead of adding properties to the JPAContainer (which is disallowed for this container as it handles its properties internally), you set a custom `com.vaadin.ui.TableFieldFactory` to your table with `Table.setTableFieldFactory(TableFieldFactory fieldFactory)`.

Comment: I've edited the post with solution that I found. I did use setGeneratedColumn() to solved my problem. thanks!